# Sed expression that converts some matches to uppercase

Tags: sed

This sed expression converts an input string into a two-line output string. Each of the two output lines are composed of substrings from the input. The first line needs to be convered into upper case:

```
s:random_stuff\(choice1\|choice2\){\([^}]*\)}:\U\1\n\2:
```

The aim is to convert

```
random_stuff_choice1{This is a sentence that MAY contain AnyThing}
random_stuff_choice2{This is another similar sentence}
```

into

```
CHOICE1
This is a sentence that MAY contain AnyThing
CHOICE2
This is another similar sentence
```

The problem I have is that \U aplies to everything following it so the second line is also uppercased. Is it possible to make \U apply to the first match only ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\E` to cancel the `\U`:

```
s:random_stuff_\(choice1\|choice2\){\([^}]*\)}:\U\1\E\n\2:
```

Comment: You missed an underscore `random_stuff_`

Answer (score 4):

With `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed 's/.*\(choice[0-9]\+\){\([^}]*\)}/\U\1\n\E\2/' file
CHOICE1
This is a sentence that MAY contain AnyThing
CHOICE2
This is another similar sentence
```

With `awk`:

```bsh
$ awk -F'{|}' 'gsub(/.*_/,""){print toupper($1)"\n"$2}' file
CHOICE1
This is a sentence that MAY contain AnyThing
CHOICE2
This is another similar sentence
```