# How to deactivate the uppercase transformation?

Tags: regex, pcre

Starting from a list of strings:

```
Hello World 1
Hello World 2
```

I'm trying to obtain the following result, with the original string in uppercase, followed by the original string (original case).

```
HELLO WORLD 1 = Hello World 1
HELLO WORLD 2 = Hello World 2
```

I've tried using the uppercase transformation but all characters that follow the `\U` are outputed in upper case:

- Search for: `(.*)\n`
- Replace with: `\U$1 = $1\n`

Output:

```
HELLO WORLD 1 = HELLO WORLD 1
HELLO WORLD 2 = HELLO WORLD 2
```

[Link](https://regex101.com/r/b54NN4/1/) to online example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137059/sed-expression-that-converts-some-matches-to-uppercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using the `\E` (Terminate Transformation).

- Search for: `(.*)\n`
- Replace with: `\U$1\E = $1\n`

It also works with other transformations like `\L` (Lowercase Transformation)

[Link](https://regex101.com/r/mWwAq7/1) to online example

Comment: I can't find any documentation that suggests this would work in PHP or PCRE library. On regex101, it mentions that \U and \E are custom regex101 property.

Comment: I just tested on some online PHP interpreter, and `\U` doesn't work in replacement string, which matches what I found in the source code. PHP only understands backreferences `\n` or `$n`

Comment: @nhahtdh: It's a PCRE feature, see [RFC](https://pcre.org/original/pcre.txt). It works for Perl and in Notepad++ and probably in many languages, for php you have to use preg_replace_callback and strtolower or strtoupper

Comment: Yes it doesn't work in PHP but it does work in perl.

Comment: @Toto: Point to me the section where it says that it supports `\U` as uppercase. By the way, the discussion is about replacement string, not the regex. The document only discusses about regex. As far as I know, PCRE library itself doesn't include replacement function or definition for replacement string - it's defined and implemented by the library/languages which uses it as backend for regex function.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Sorry, my bad. PCRE doesn't support `37  PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u` this is clearly said in `COMPILATION ERROR CODES` in the RFC.